# How do I insert value into labels using dojo

Tags: dojo, label

I am trying to dynamically insert the values in the labels which I will hide from sighted users but will be read by screen readers for visually impaired users that are displayed in the columns. How can I accomplish this using dojo?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dojo Labels</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.3.2/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        width: 154px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 51%; height: 204px;">
    <tr>
        <td class="style1">
            &nbsp;
            <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="Checkbox1"></label>
        </td>
        <td>
           John
        </td>
        <td>
            Doe
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1">
            &nbsp;
            <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="Checkbox2"></label>
        </td>
        <td>
            Jane
        </td>
        <td>
            Doe
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1">
            &nbsp;
            <input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="Checkbox3"></label>
        </td>
        <td>
           John
        </td>
        <td>
           Smith
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need to dynamically change label then you can try this:

```
dojo.query("label[for=Checkbox1]")[0].innerHTML = "text";
```

But if you need logic to detect if it is a screen reader or a browser then I cannot help. But you probably could always render label with text just add style display:none;

```
<label for="Checkbox2" style="display:none;">text</label>
```

Comment: I already have the css written and yes I am using a display of none. I just needed the direction on how to write the dojo code and you assisted thanks.

Comment: You should set `textContent` if you can (to avoid script injection), not `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly sure if I understand exactly what you are doing, but dojo provides a method that allows you to modify a DOM node's attribute values. It's called [dojo.attr()](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.2/dojo.attr)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one will help.

To get label content : dijit.byId("btnButtonName").get("label")=="SomeName");

To set label content : dijit.byId("btnButtonName").set("label", "SomeName");